# Writing code in VBA, SQL statement has table parameter

Tags: sql, vba

I'm having issues with a SQL query in Excel VBA. I would definitely be writing a stored procedure, however, this is prohibited in our Salesforce Database (unless you're an administrator).

The below code works perfectly fine in SQL and performs well, however, when I place it in VBA it comes back with an error message stating

> Must declare table variable "@ServiceRequestSELECT

and I'm not sure why. I have also tried using a temp table and that does not work either. I'm sure it's a stupid syntax error somewhere.

```
"INSERT INTO @ServiceRequest" & _
"SELECT t6.name, t1.Status, format(t1.[CreatedDate], 'MM-dd-yyyy'), t5.Name, t2.Name, t1.Escalation__c" & _
"FROM [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Case] t1" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Policy__c] t2 ON t1.[Policy__c] = t2.[Id]" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Account] t3 ON t2.[Office__c] = t3.[Id]" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Contact] t4 ON t1.[Broker_of_Record__c] = t4.[Id]" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[User] t5 ON t1.[OwnerId] = t5.[Id]" & _
"LEFT JOIN [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[RecordType] t6 ON t1.[RecordTypeId] = t6.[Id]" & _
"WHERE t3.[MVP_Status__c] = 'Implemented'" & _
"AND t5.[Profile__c] = 'Customer Loyalty Manager'" & _
"and t3.Source_System_Natural_Key__c = '" & Range("Source_System_Natural_Key") & "'" & _
"and t1.CreatedDate > Dateadd(year, -1, getdate())" & _
"ORDER BY t1.ClosedDate desc" & _
"Select count(case when [SR_Type] = [General Policy Maintenance] then 1 else NULL End) as [General Policy Maintenance]," & _
"count(case when [SR_Type] = [Information Request/Inquiry] then 1 else NULL End) as [Information Request/Inquiry]," & _
"count(case when [SR_Type] = [Service Issue] then 1 else NULL End) as [Service Issue]," & _
"count(case when [Escalation] in ([Open],[Resolved],[Monitor]) then 1 else NULL end) as [Escalation] from @ServiceRequest"
Set rs = con.Execute(sSQL)
If rs.EOF = False Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Console").Cells(26, 3).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Try adding a space after @ServiceRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing spaces in between pretty much every concatenated part.

As an example, this:

```
"insert into @ServiceRequest" & _
"SELECT t6.name, t1.Status, format(t1.[CreatedDate], 'MM-dd-yyyy'), t5.Name, t2.Name, t1.Escalation__c" & _
"FROM [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Case] t1" & _
```

Generates a string like:

```
insert into @ServiceRequestSELECT t6.name, t1.Status, format(t1.[CreatedDate], 'MM-dd-yyyy'), t5.Name, t2.Name, t1.Escalation__cFROM [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Case] t1
                         --^--
```

You would need:

```
"insert into @ServiceRequest " & _
"SELECT t6.name, t1.Status, format(t1.[CreatedDate], 'MM-dd-yyyy'), t5.Name, t2.Name, t1.Escalation__c " & _
"FROM [Salesforce_Reporting].[dbo].[Case] t1 " & _
...
```

Comment: did that, now I'm getting an error stating Incorrect Syntax near '.' and it's pointing to the bottom of my code where is states "Set rs = con.Execute(sSQL)"